# What's the most efficient way to ignore code in lua?

Tags: performance, lua

I have a chunk of lua code that I'd like to be able to (selectively) ignore.  I don't have the option of not reading it in and sometimes I'd like it to be processed, sometimes not, so I can't just comment it out (that is, there's a whole bunch of blocks of code and I either have the option of reading *none* of them or reading *all* of them).  I came up with two ways to implement this (there may well be more - I'm very much a beginner): either enclose the code in a function and then call or not call the function (and once I'm sure I'm passed the point where I would call the function, I can set it to `nil` to free up the memory) or enclose the code in an `if ... end` block.  The former has slight advantages in that there are several of these blocks and using the former method makes it easier for one block to load another even if the main program didn't request it, but the latter seems the more efficient.  However, not knowing much, I don't know if the efficiency saving is worth it.

So how much more efficient is:

```
if false then
    -- a few hundred lines
end
```

than

```
throwaway = function ()
    -- a few hundred lines
end
throwaway = nil  -- to ensure that both methods leave me in the same state after garbage collection
```

?

If it depends a lot on the lua implementation, how big would the "few hundred lines" need to be to reliably spot the difference, and what sort of stuff should it include to best test (the main use of the blocks is to define a load of possibly useful functions)?

Comment: Recent Lua versions are compiling to bytecode, so some hundred lines of parsing won't make a big runtime difference if the code is not executed, whatever mean you use for that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch So there's no efficiency checks in `if false then ... end`?  (I guess the situation actually wouldn't come up so often that *at read time* the state of the conditional was known so it makes sense that there's no check.)  Thanks for the comment, by the way.

Comment: Here's a bigger question: why do you think it matters? You're using a *scripting language*; performance obviously isn't paramount in what you're doing. So do you have reason to believe that either pattern will be noticeably slower than the other? Just use whatever best describes what you're trying to do for someone *reading* the code; if it's a performance issue, then you can resolve it *after* you know that it's a performance problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm using a scripting language because it's all that I have access to (it's on an iPad ...).  Whilst performance may not be *paramount*, I don't want to deliberately cripple myself.  Also, I'm at that stage where what I do now will probably get "set in stone" as switching to a different method later will be seriously annoying so I'd rather get it right first go.  Lastly, as a mathematician, being pragmatic doesn't come easy.

Answer (score 4):

Lua's not smart enough to dump the code for the function, so you're not going to save any memory.

In terms of speed, you're talking about a different of nanoseconds which happens *once* per program execution. [It's harming *your* efficiency to worry about this, which has virtually no relevance to actual performance.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) Write the code that you feel expresses your *intent* most clearly, without trying to be [clever](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoSimpleThings). If you run into performance issues, it's going to be a million miles away from this decision.

If you want to save memory, which is understandable on a mobile platform, you could put your conditional code in it's own module and never load it at all of not needed (if your framework supports it; e.g. MOAI does, Corona doesn't).

Comment: Not even with garbage collection? Ah, well.  Thanks for the links - very useful perspectives.

Comment: It's very easy to test yourself: `collectgarbage('collect')` will force a collection cycle and `collectgarbage('count')` will show you how much memory Lua is using.

Comment: I'm pleasantly surprised to find that those work in the particular implementation.  Thanks for giving me the tools I need.

Answer (score 2):

If there is really ***a lot*** of unused code, you can define it as a collection of Strings and `loadstring()` it when needed. Storing functions as strings will reduce the initial compile time, however of most functions the string representation probably takes up more memory than it's compiled form and what you save when compiling is probably not significant before a few thousand lines... Just saying.

If you put this code in a table, you could compile it transparently through a metatable for minimal performance impact on *repeated* calls.

Example code

```
local code_uncompiled = {
   f = [=[
      local x, y = ...;
      return x+y;
   ]=]
}
code = setmetatable({}, {
   __index = function(self, k)
      self[k] = assert(loadstring(code_uncompiled[k]));
      return self[k];
   end
});

local ff = code.f; -- code of x gets compiled here
ff = code.f; -- no compilation here
for i=1, 1000 do
   print( ff(2*i, -i) ); -- no compilation here either
   print( code.f(2*i, -i) ); -- no compile either, but table access (slower)
end
```

The beauty of it is that this compiles as needed and you don't really have to waste another thought on it, it's just like storing a function in a table and allows for a lot of flexibility.

Another advantage of this solution is that when the amount of dynamically loaded code gets out of hand, you could transparently change it to load code from external files on demand through the __index function of the metatable. Also, you can mix compiled and uncompiled code by populating the "code" table with "real" functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the one that makes the code more legible to you first. If it runs fast enough on your target machine, use that.

If it doesn't run fast enough, try the other one.

Comment: One of the factors is scalability: I'll keep adding to the central repository so although I won't detect it now, I might in a few months time.

Comment: Repeat the same script 100000 times then.

Answer (score 0):

lua can ignore multiple lines by:

```
function dostuff()
   blabla
   faaaaa

   --[[
   ignore this
   and this
   maybe this
   this as well
   ]]--
end
```

Comment: I could not find the `--[[ ... ]]--` syntax in the documentation; now I can stop commenting out each one of multiple lines with `--`